# Ratchet - alternative to ZeroMQ

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

I am new to making WebSockets applications, and I am trying to set up Ratchet (as server-side will be completely in PHP).

Everything was working correctly, until I got to "Push notifications" part. There is written, that you can use plain sockets for push notifications, but they prefer using ZeroMQ. Can you please show me an example / point me to some tutorial, how to use that plain sockets? (I don't want to use ZeroMQ because of limited access to production server, almost without possibility to install stuff there)

Or if there is a library for it, which doesn't require installation of some extensions stuff, can you send me to their docs?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the question? For what exact purpose are you going to use plain socket?

Comment: @ArunPoudel i just want an alternative to ZeroMQ, something that can send push notifications. I dont know the exact purpose now, but push notifications are usefull everywhere.

Comment: Then, you can use ratchet for sure. At [link](http://futurehome.no), we use ratchet(websocket) for both internal as well as external communication. And it works well.